# Bad Token Exception - Unable to add Window . Happens only after Activity Restart

Tags: java, android, exception, view, android-view

So, I have this code where I do a HttpPost and wait for a response which is given back to a handler. And in the handler block, I show up a ProgressDialog. Everything seems to work fine until I restart the activity using this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

The code for 1st Handler is this

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (0 < msg.what) {
        } else {
            if (msg.getData() != null) {
                String s = msg.getData().getString(getResources().getString(R.string.BundleTextKey));
                if (s!=null) {
                                try{
                                    POSTMethods post_obj = new POSTMethods(messageHandleralert,context);
                                    String sender = ValuesHolder.user;
                                    mprogDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Tab_Activity.this, "", "creating pending request");
                                    post_obj.createPendingRequest(sender);

                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(Tab_Activity.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I do a Post call thru createPendingRequest and this response is handled by another handler which is this

```
public Handler messageHandleralert = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        switch(msg.what){
        case 5:
            try{
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                DateClass date_obj = new DateClass();
                String date = date_obj.getDate();
                map.put("date",date);
                map.put("sender_email", sender);
                mOutAdapter.insert(map, 0);
                mprogDialog.dismiss();
                String sData = date+" "+sender;
                System.out.println(active);
                showAlert showDialog = new showAlert(mOutAdapter,context,null,null);
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = showDialog.createAlert("Received Payment Request", "Confirm Details of the Payee", true, false,true,sData);
                alert.show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                mprogDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Tab_Activity.this, "Error... Do it Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            try{
                Toast.makeText(Tab_Activity.this, "Error. Check Connection and Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mprogDialog.dismiss();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

So the error shows up at ProgressDialog line in my 1st handler block.

```
mprogDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Tab_Activity.this, "", "creating pending request");
```

which is

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41520070 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Actually, I can get rid of this line by not displaying any progress. But the AlertDialog in my 2nd Handler block is required and it throws the same error on activity restart.

I tried including

```
(!isFinishing())
```

but that doesn't work. The code is never reached on activity restart if I use it.

Is there a work around to get through this issue ? or am i doing something wrong ? Some help or even links on this will be appreciated

Logcat:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@414f3fa8 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
at org.example.pay.Tab_Activity$1.handleMessage(Tab_Activity.java:159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```